# Error in accessing dictionary object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an `NSDictionary` *input with 2 key/value pairs

```
[0]="@id":@"random"
[1]="@val":@"100"
```

These are the contents of my `NSDictionary`,when I write the following code

```
for(NSDictionary *inputVal in input)

if(inputVal[@"id"] == field)
```

My variable field is a `NSString` and contains random, I get the error

```
[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I know that this error means that I am trying a dictionary operation on string object i.e. I am expecting a dictionary object but have a string

But my question is I do have a `NSDictionary` object only

Answer (score 1):

`for(NSDictionary *inputVal in input)` iterates for all the keys.

So you should use:

```
for(NSDictionary *key in input){
    if(input[key] == field){ // notice: used input dictionary here.
     ....
    }
 }
```

Also, you need not to iterate to find the value from the key, you can directly fetch if using the key as:

```
if (input[@"id"] == field) {
   ...
}
```

After doing above manipulation, you are comparing the value with a string with `==`, if you are sure you need to compare the address of both then it OK. Otherwise you need to use `isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a `NSDictionary` doesn't give you dictionaries, it iterates over `NSString` keys:

```
for (NSString *inputKey in input) { //first value will be "id", second will be "val"
   if ([inputKey isEqual:@"id"] && [input[inputKey] isEqual:field]) {
   }
}
```

You probably don't even need iteration:

```
if ([input[@"id"] isEqual:field]) {
   //do something
}
```

Also note [Anoop Vaidya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529972/669586) and his comment about `==` and `isEquals:`.